# How to query an 'Object' type field in parse.

Tags: parse-platform

I have a `Parse.User` with a column type of object named availability with two fields, `status` and `timestamp`, how would I query `Parse.User` to find those with a `status` of `busy`?

For instance:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo('availability', {status: 'busy'});
query.find()...
```

Is what I expected may work but did not. Note that the `availability` field is not another `Parse.Object`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the dot notation for multi-level queries:

```
query.equalTo('availability.status', 'busy');
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, don't know why I never thought to try this myself.