# Parse & Swift: Column with multiple keys

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I've a problem getting an object that has a column with multiple [String:Int] values. In my case I'm storing a message that users can like or dislike. The message object has the column `likes` which contains a `Dict[String, Int]` that stores the `userID` and the like value (+1/-1).
In the backend it looks like:

```
"likes": {
  "123": 1,
  "456": -1,
  "789": 1
},
```

I was able to get the results until one week ago using:

```
query.whereKey("likes." + userID, equalTo: 1)
```

But unfortunately I'm getting the error message:

> [Error]: invalid key name: likes.123 (Code: 105, Version: 1.12.0)

even though it was working a few days ago.

okay, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm trying to get all messages that a user has liked before. Therefore, I want to select all messages that contain the userID in the "likes" column.

The class is called "message" has an attribute "likes" that again contains a Dict[UserID, Value]. The complete query looks like this:

`let query = Message.query()!`

`query.whereKey("likes." + user, equalTo: 1)`

and the object in the backend looks like this:

```
{"_id": "123456789",
"message": "Test",
"likes": { "123": 1, "456": -1, "789": 1 }
}
```

I hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the value for `likes.` but actually your key is `likes` , remove **dot** from your code.

**Your modified Code:**

```
query.whereKey("likes", equalTo: 1)
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if the **dot** is remove then I still get the same error message: "[Error]: invalid key name: likes123 (Code: 105, Version: 1.12.0)"

Comment: Here `likes` is an object, if you want to access value of `123` in likes object you need to use like this `let value = likes.123`

Comment: please, see answer above

Comment: any suggestions so far?

Comment: For my first solution I used this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306318/how-to-query-an-object-type-field-in-parse

But unfortunately this is not possible anymore